# How to spread the dataframe using values as column names and fill with counts of same cells in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below

```
x1 = c('a','bd','c',NA)
x2 = c('cd', 'fd', 'g', 'ew')
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(x1,x2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[image]

And I want to convert this dataframe to like below dataframe

[image]

I was trying to spread original dataframe using tidyr.
How can I convert this dataframe?

Comment: Hi and welcome, please put your data in code block and not as an image. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

```
u <- na.omit(as.vector(t(df))) 
dfout <- `names<-`(data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) +(u %in% x) ))),u)
```

such that

```
> dfout
   a bd c cd fd g ew
x1 1  1 1  0  0 0  0
x2 0  0 0  1  1 1  1
```

Comment: Is there any option removing NA?

Answer (score 4):

We can reshape into 'long' format  with `pivot_longer` after creating a column of rownames (`rownames_to_column`), and then convert it back to 'wide' with `pivot_wider` and change the column 'rn' back to rownames (`column_to_rownames`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  select(-name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  column_to_rownames('rn')
#   a bd c cd fd g ew
#x1 1  1 1  0  0 0  0
#x2 0  0 0  1  1 1  1
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R`

```
table(rep(row.names(df), ncol(df)), unlist(df))
#     a bd c cd ew fd g
#  x1 1  1 1  0  0  0 0
#  x2 0  0 0  1  1  1 1
```

Comment: First method makes an error 'could not find function "pivot_longer"'

Comment: @CharlieYoon  It is from `tidyr`.   I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Comment: @CharlieYoon  Wouldn't the `table` solution work for you?